# Crystal reports object hierarchy datasource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I need to create a report from a .NET object, and this works fine as long as it is a simple object with no hierarchy. But I need to bind to an object hierarchy like

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber{get;set;}
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines{get;set;}
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int LineNo {get;set;}
}
```

Is this possible? when I update the Database fields in the Field explorer, the List<> property does not appear.

Comment: Are you putting anything in that list?

Comment: And why don't you put the OrderNumber in the list with the OrderLines?

Comment: The property does not appear in the designer, so no data exists yet, im just designing the report, and cannot access the OrderlinesProperty, since its a list it seems. If I add another string property, it will appear just fine. The above classes are just examples, to explain my needs.

Comment: Have you tried just the list in the Order class, without the OrderNumber?

Comment: I have not been able to make this work, so I have been forced to create a DataSet instead, and fill this with the data before creating the report.